# Use dynamic linq or sql query in report generator

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, linq, report

I want to create a simple report generator in my project (ASP.Net, C#). I need to below futures that I can implement these by **linq query** or **Sql query**:

> End user (user who does not have programming information) selects
>   entity name from a `Dropdown`.

**linq query**

```
dbContext.dbSet
```

**Sql query**

```
SELECT * FROM selectedTable
```

> End user select fields of entity from `checklistbox` (These fields
>   used for bind to `GridView`). Create `TextBoxes` for each one of them.
>   End user enters the value for filter grid later.

**linq query**

Create custom `where clause`as `customExpression` with selected fields and use it in below query.

```
dbContext.dbSet.Where(customExpression).ToList()
```

**Sql query**

```
SELECT * FROM selectedTable
WHERE CustomWhereCondition
```

I used **Sql query** in my previous projects but I tend to use **linq query** in new project. `dynamic Where conditions` may be developed in the future and may be I can not do them in `linq query` or more difficult than the `Sql query`.
I doubt what method to use.

It would be very helpful if someone could explain which method is better to use in my project.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you strongly use ‍`LINQ Query` for some important reasons.

- Scalability and flexibility.
- Security: Avoids SQL injection.
- If the name of the table or its columns changes, it will be reflected in the view you don't need to change it in `LINQ Query` unlike the string `SQL Query`.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve it by using a predicate.

```
public static Func<T, bool> GetWhereLambda<T>(string paramName, dynamic paramValue)
    {            
        var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "s");
        var classExpr = GetEqualsExpr(param, paramName, paramValue);
        return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(classExpr, param).Compile();
    }

    private static Expression GetEqualsExpr(ParameterExpression param,
                             string property,
                             dynamic value)
    {
        Expression prop = Expression.Property(param, property);
        Expression val = Expression.Constant(value, prop.Type);
        return Expression.Equal(prop, val);
    }
```

Usage:

```
   Func<T, bool> myLambda = GetWhereLambda<T>(paramName, paramValue);
   var resultset = dbContext.dbSet.Where(myLambda).ToList();
```

This code sample only helps you with dynamic 'Where param equals to value' expression. You can follow the same process for greater than, less than and create your own expression tree helper.

Comment: Thx for answer. I know methods that I can do it by `linq`. My question is which one is better? Why?

Comment: You can generate custom expressions for simple queries using the above method. This will help with the performance as well as you won't be fetching all the records and then apply where conditions on it. Expression trees generate sql queries internally. It ultimately boils down to code maintainability. If you are okay with hardcoding the sql statements in your code, You can solve it by writing your own sql statements.